# Como somar valores em uma coleção no cloud Firestore em flutter dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

Como posso somar o campo ‘Valor’ - imagem abaixo - usando a linguagem de programação Dart no flutter? Tentei fazer como no código abaixo mas não deu certo.

```
RecuperarLista() async {
int a;
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
FirebaseUser usuarioLogado = await auth.currentUser();
Firestore db = Firestore.instance;
db.collection("meus Produtos").snapshots().listen(
        ( snapshot ){
      for( DocumentSnapshot item in snapshot.documents ) {
        var dados = item.data;
        int somar=0;
      somar =dados['Valor'].values.reduce((sum, element) => (sum + element));
print("somar do valor è"+ somar.toString());

      }
```

[image: Cloud Firestore]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a variável do total fora do for e então some os valores dentro:

```
int total = 0;
for (DocumentSnapshot item in snapshot.documents) {
  var dados = item.data;
  total += dados['Valor'];
  print("total: " + total.toString());
}
```

Comment: Deu certo,muito obrigado.